# Permission denied to connect to my remote server via ssh on windows

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, putty

with putty gen I generated a public and private key, and placed the private key on (`C:\Users\toto\.ssh`)
but when I try to connect I have (permission denied)
And here is the display on the terminal after the command

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits r‚serv‚s.

C:\Users\toto>ssh instance@ipaddr
instance@ipaddr: Permission denied (publickey).

C:\Users\toto>ssh -v instance@ipaddr
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Connecting to ipaddr [ipaddr] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubunt
u-3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000
000
debug1: Authenticating to ipaddr as 'instance'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or
directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file
or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file
or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit
> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:rAcaUaTH9l7EIAtwkIhtCTWEHLji57CSdkKi
AS64cWU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or
directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file
or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file
or directory
debug1: Host 'ipaddr' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or dir
ectory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.
com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nis
tp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-s
ha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\toto/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
instance@ipaddr: Permission denied (publickey).

C:\Users\toto>
```

Je suis allé dans le fichier `C:\Users\toto\.ssh`sur le fichier `key_private.ppk` , j'ai désactivé l'héritage puis j'ai converti les autorisations héritées en autorisations explicites sur cet objet , puis j'ai tout supprimé (y compris admin, utilisateur, groupes d'utilisateurs) puis j'ai ajouté mon objet utilisateur en lui donnant plein contrôler et enregistrer les modifications, mais lorsque j'exécute la commande       `ssh nameinstance@ipaddr`, j'ai toujours Autorisation refusée (clé publique) A noté que `C:\Users\toto\.ssh` j'ai les fichiers suivants

```
key_private.ppk
known_hosts
```

Comment: What are the permissions (provide a screenshot of that window) on those keys?

Comment: What is the name of the key file that ssh is supposed to use for this connection?

Comment: @kenster , the name of the private key is: key_private.ppk that is on C:\Users\toto\.ssh